# How do I parameterize this figure?

Tags: integration

I have to find the line integral for: the integral of $(x^2+y^2) dy$ where $C$ is given in the figure.

[image]

I tried splitting up the line/curve in the figure into $C1$ and $C2$. I parameterized $C1$ as: $x=3t$ and $y=0$, then I found that $dy=0$ so the integral for that part would be $0$. And for $C2$, I found the parameterization to be: $x=3$ and $y=3t$. Then I found that $dy=3dt$ and then I did the integral for $C2$. But my answer came out to be: $27(12)$ which doesn't match my book's answer of $36$. Could someone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
I = \int_C (x^2 + y^2) dy = \int_{C_1} (x^2 + y^2) dy 0 \int_{C_2} (x^2 + y^2) dy
$$
Parametrisation for the first path is $(3t, 0)$ and for the second path $(3, 3t)$. Now
$$
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 (9 + 0)\cdot 0 + \int_0^1 (9 + 9t^2)3dt \\
&= 3\left[ 9t + 9 \cdot \frac{t^3}{3} \right]_0^1 \\
&= 9 + 9 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \\
&= 27 + 9 \\
&= 36
\end{align*}
$$

So it seems that your parametrisations are ok. You should check your calculations.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, can you explain why we use 0 and 1 as the integration limits? And not 0 and 3?

Comment: Integration limits are 0 and 1 because I chose the parametrisation so that for example the $C_2$ path is $(3,3t)$. Now, when $t=0$, we have $(3,0)$ and when $t=1$ we have $(3,3)$. So we integrate from $(3,0)$ to $(3,3)$ alogn a straight line. I could choose a parametrisation so that the integration goes from $0$ to $3$, for example $(3,t)$ goes from $(3,0)$ to $(3,3)$, when $t$ goes from 0 to 3.

Comment: Ah! I see, thank you so much!